# Can't run js file with node.js on mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I'm new to node.js and javascript. I install node.js successfully,but when I run the js file in terminal on mac,I got error.

```
han:~ cuibosoft$ node example.js 

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/cuibosoft/example.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I'm sure example.js is at /Users/cuibosoft/. I don't know why node can't it.

Comment: That's rather odd. Can `cat` find it? (`cat example.js`)

Comment: `node start /Users/cubiosoft/example.js` or while you are in correct directory, `node start example.js`

Comment: @icktoofay No, it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might think it is, but judging from your comment, `example.js` cannot be in `/Users/cuibosoft`. If it's on your desktop, then it's really in `/Users/cuibosoft/Desktop`. If you want to move it to your home directory proper, you can open your home directory in Finder by pressing <kbd>⌘⇧H</kbd>.

Comment: But when I run `ls`, example.js is showed in terminal.

Comment: Now I add a file "example.txt" to the same dictionary, and run `cat example.txt`, and it works well.

Comment: @nimingzhe2008: Maybe it's got a space in the filename somewhere. You could try using tab completion, typing e.g. `node ex<TAB>` and letting your shell try to complete it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I change the file name to some.js, and it works well now. So strange.